# WP_Query поиск по meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

У меня есть мета поле со значениями типо a1, a2, a11 и т.д.
Я делаю поиск по нему таким образом

```
array(
'key' => 'a',
'value' => 'a1',
'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
```

Но появилась проблема, **LIKE делает не точный поиск а совпадение**. т.е при a1 так же выводятся записи с полем a11. Как можно исправить это, чтобы поиск был точно по a1? **Раньше в файле wp-includes/meta.php была строка**

```
$meta_value = '%' . like_escape( $meta_value ) . '%';
```

можно было убрать проценты, и поиск работал точно. в новых версиях такого (по крайней мере в этом файле) нет

Comment: 'compare' => '=' не выводит вообще ничего

'value' => array('a1'),
'compare' => 'IN'
тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
'key' => 'a',
'type' => 'BINARY',
'value' => 'a1',
'compare' => '='
),
```

Будет выводить только если значения строго, a=a1.
Было б хорошо написать весь запрос(параметры), возможно ошибка есть дополнительно в самом массиве аргументов.